# handle resolver errors in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, resolve

I'm using `resolve` to prefetch data when navigating from one component to another. Now I want to stay in the same component that originated the routing, when any errors occur on fetching data.

I've looked at lot of blogs, tutorials...etc and most of them suggest throwing the error should stop the navigation, but in my case I've to do `this.router.navigate([`/${this.router.url}`]);` to stay in the same component.

I'm trying to see if its possible to stop naviagation without explcitly calling `router.navigate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) or [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) to stay on the same route without using `this.router.navigate`.

.

Comment: `CanActivate` or `CanDeactivate` happens before `resolve`, so it won't work in my scenario

Answer (score 0):

A little late here, but here's how you can *cancel* the navigation without having to throwing an error.

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

resolve(): Observable<Product> {
  return this.service.getProduct().pipe(
    catchError(() => {
      // do something, like show a toastr message or log to console..

      return EMPTY;
    })
  );
}
```

`EMPTY` is basically an `Observable` that does not emit any items and just emits the `complete` notification.
You can read more about it [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY).